# Where can I find Blood Dragons wearing brain-cages?

Tags: achievements, far-cry-3-blood-dragon

I am trying to get the achievement 'Set Them Free' which requires that I disable 5 brain cages on Blood Dragons. I've completed the story missions and during that only encountered a few such Blood Dragons, and have destroyed the brain cages pretty easily. However now that the story missions are over I can't seem to find any Blood Dragons still wearing the cage.

Is there a place I can go to find Blood Dragons with brain cages?

I still have a garrison left unliberated but mostly everything else has been done. Have I just missed some crucial Blood Dragons during story play through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few that guard garrisons, and you'll encounter a few during the campaign missions.  I didn't find enough this way, personally, and [so I had to farm them a bit.](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/far-cry-3-blood-dragon-achievement-guide/)

> For Set Them Free, you’ll need to target blood dragon braincages. Only some of the blood dragons in the game have braincages – you’ll find these dragons near Omega Force garrisons and during story missions. I haven’t seen many roaming the wilderness, but they do pop up from time to time.

Just run around the island, and you'll occasionally see one, usually with a compliment of cybersoldiers.

Comment: I don't really follow your 'farming' route here. If I read that article and quote right it sounds like my best bet is just to keep visiting the unliberated garrisons hoping a brain-caged blood dragon will be there, yes?

Comment: @JonW, I just ran around the island, essentially.  They're random encounters.  There was only one or maybe two I found guarding garrisons.

Comment: I had an encounter with one in the underground garrison, and I met the others during a story mission.

Comment: @CyberSkull, yeah, I didn't *quite* find enough during the story mission.  I remember that one garrison though.  I found a group of cybersoldiers hanging out with one randomly on the island to round out my count.  I've seen one or two more since.

Comment: No, there aren't enough during the story mission. I had already encountered one or two wandering about, then I got the achievement when I finished off the last one from the story mission.

Answer (score 2):

I just got all five brain cages during the mission where you burn the three groups of eggs. Hit the brain cages on the first two dragons protecting their eggs. Escape to the corridor you entered through and use the left wall / barricade to avoid their laser attacks while you take them out. Once you kill those two, a single dragon will respawn next to the eggs on your left. It's even sleeping! Wake it up by destroying its brain cage and run back to the corridor. Kill the third dragon and a fourth appears. This time just destroy the brain cage and finish burning the eggs (which is easier now with just one dragon to evade.) When you get to the elevator, another dragon comes after you with a fifth brain cage. You know what to do...

It's a little tough killing three dragons without the benefit of replenishing your sniper ammo in-between, but if you plant mines and C400 on the path before getting their attention, it helps. Make sure to wait until they expose the weak spot on their belly to make better use of your ammo.